# Cannot completely uninstall a repository/app

Tags: wine, uninstall, winetricks, software-uninstall

I installed Wine to run Windows applications on Ubuntu. As soon as I opened Wine a message popped up saying it needed to download and install some stuff to run Windows apps. I clicked okay and as they were being downloaded/installed, my PC shut down because my battery drained. I turned my PC back on and tried to open Wine (the app's called Winetricks) but it won't open at all. It's logo appears in the launcher but it closes after a few seconds. I don't know what to do. I tried completely uninstalling it using Synaptic or purging it via the terminal to install it again. These methods 'work', they uninstall Winetricks and Wine Configuration, that comes along Winetricks, but I install Wine again from the beginning and it still won't open. I really need to get Wine working. I know Play on Linux is an alternative but I've heard it doesn't work as well as Wine. I need newbie-type help, I've had Ubuntu for a day and I basically know nothing. I'd appreciate detailed help for me to get things done. Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: When trying to install Wine sometimes I get the message ''Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.'' I suppose that I basically need a way to **completely remove** Wine, configuration files, index files, anything it downloaded.